# What is the structure of "lack of something"?

Tags: grammar, possessives, noun-phrases

The word lack can be used either as a verb or noun. When it is used as a noun, such as **"lack of water"**. Is the preposition phrase **"of water"** an attribute? Just like the window of the house. Or it is a noun phrase as a whole?

Comment: No: it's a preposition phrase functioning as complement of "lack".

Comment: @BillJ Can you explain to me how to differentiate preposition phrase functioning as complement and possessive?

Comment: Genitive NPs are marked either by an apostrophe _'s_ (**Ed's** car). or else by a genitive personal pronoun ("**his** car"). Syntactically, of phrases are not genitive (possessive).

Comment: @BillJ Edited it into richardec's answer.

Comment: @HenryWang see my answer below ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's not "of water" in one phrase, instead it's "lack of" in one phrase.

"of water" doesn't make any sense, but "lack of" does.

You could see it on the [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lack%20of):

It mentions:

> not having (the thing specified)

As @BillJ mentioned, it's actually a preposition phrase functioning as complement of "lack".